# How to delete an element from a list in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
v = range(1e10, -1e10, step=-1e8) # velocities [cm/s]
deleteat!(v, findall(x->x==0,v))
```

I want to delete the value `0` from `v`. Following [this tutorial](https://julia.school/julia/arrays/#how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-julia-array-by-index-number), I tried `deleteat!` but I get the error

```
MethodError: no method matching deleteat!(::StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}, ::Vector{Int64})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In addition to `Range` not being a `Vector`, it is important to note that ranges are *immutable*, so it's not just `deleteat!` that won't work, but any of the mutating functions, like `push!`, `pop!`, `splice!`, etc. Ranges are clever data structures that work like `Vector`s for access, does not explicitly store all its elements, and therefore cannot be modified. You always just create a new range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the type that is returned by the function `range`.

```
typeof(range(1e10, -1e10, step=-1e8))
```

The above yields to

```
StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}
```

Calling the help function for the function `deleteat!`.

```
? deleteat!()
```

> deleteat!(a::Vector, inds)
>
> Remove the items at the indices given by inds, and return the > modified a. Subsequent items are shifted to fill the resulting gap.
>
> inds can be either an **iterator** or a **collection** of sorted and > unique integer indices, or a boolean vector of the same length as a with true indicating entries to delete.

We can convert the returned type of `range` using `collect`. Try the following code.

```
v = collect(range(1e10, -1e10, step=-1e8))
deleteat!(v,findall(x->x==0,v))
```

Notice that we can shorten `x->x==0` to `iszero` which yields to

```
v = collect(range(1e10, -1e10, step=-1e8))
deleteat!(v,findall(iszero,v))
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `filter!` or `filter`:

```
julia> filter!(!=(0), [1,0,2,0,4])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 4
```

In case of a `range` you can `collect` it or use:

```
julia> filter(!=(0), range(2, -2, step=-1))
4-element Vector{Int64}:
  2
  1
 -1
 -2
```

However for big ranges you might just not want to materialize them to save the memory footprint. In that case you could use:

```
(x for x in range(2, -2, step=-1) if x !== 0)
```

To see what is being generated you need to `collect` it:

```
julia> collect(x for x in range(2, -2, step=-1) if x !== 0)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
  2
  1
 -1
 -2
```

Comment: When I try this with my code, using `filter!(!=(0), v)`, I get `setindex! not defined for StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}`

Comment: @Dila Use `filter` (without the `!`) instead: `v = filter(!=(0), range(1e10, -1e10, step=-1e8))
`. An advantage of this method over the collect-then-delete method is that here the Vector is formed directly without the unwanted element (`0` in this case). When you `collect` then `deleteat!`, the full Vector has to be formed, then the deletion happens and the elements to the right of the `0` (which is half of them) all need to be shifted left to fill in the gap. Using `filter` avoids that costly two-step process.